# How to change tableViewHeight in tableViewController (Swift)

Tags: swift, height, tableview

I've created a tableViewController, set all custom cell settings and made data displaying, but how can I change it's height so that it will not looks like that?

[image]

How to resize it to be lower than status bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to mess around with the height use this.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 30 // what ever number you want.
}
```

or if you want to hide the status bar us this

```
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

...to change Inset.

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

Comment: I want neither to hide status bar nor to change row height. I want to change tableView height a little bit less than it is.

Comment: That's better but I had to delete all "f" symbols. Thx

Comment: my bad. that was in Obj-c